# How to validate date in R

Tags: r

I have a date in the format `dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm:ss`
What is the best and easiest way to validate this date?

I tried

```
d <- format.Date(date, format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

But how can I catch the error when an illegal date is passed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple way:

```
d <- try(as.Date(date, format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
if("try-error" %in% class(d) || is.na(d)) {
  print("That wasn't correct!")
}
```

**Explanation:** `format.Date` uses `as.Date` internally to convert `date` into an object of the `Date` class. However, it does not use a format option, so `as.Date` uses the default format, which is `%Y-%m-%d`and then `%Y/%m/%d`.

The `format` option from `format.Date` is used only for the output, not for the parsing. Quoting from the `as.Date` man page:

> The ‘as.Date’ methods accept character strings, factors, logical
> ‘NA’ and objects of classes ‘"POSIXlt"’ and ‘"POSIXct"’.  (The
> last is converted to days by ignoring the time after midnight in
> the representation of the time in specified timezone, default
> UTC.)  Also objects of class ‘"date"’ (from package ‘date’) and
> ‘"dates"’ (from package ‘chron’).  Character strings are processed
> as far as necessary for the format specified: any trailing
> characters are ignored.

However, when you directly call `as.Date` with a format specification, nothing else will be allowed than what fits your format.

**See also**: `?as.Date`

Comment: getting "That wasn't correct!" for input "01-13-1986 00:00:00"      but No error on "39-12-1986 00:00:00"                               do how can I ensure the validity day for a date ??

Comment: That's correct but how can I check the validity of day as no message for date having day greater than 31??

Comment: Nice. See my answer for a similar vectorized solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the `gsubfn` package.  This has functions (`gsubfn` specifically) that work like other regular expression functions to match pieces to a string, but then it calls a user supplied function and passes the matching pieces to this function.  So you would write your own function that looks at the year, moth, and day and makes sure that they are in the correct ranges (and the range for day can depend on the passed month and year.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful if flexibility is desired in a date-time entry.

I have a function where I want to allow either a date-only entry or a date-time entry, then set a flag - for use inside the function only. I'm calling this flag `data_type`. The flag will be used later in the larger function to select units for getting a difference in two dates with `difftime`. (In most cases, the function will be perfectly fine with date only, but in some cases a user might need a shorter time frame. I don't want to inconvenience users with the shorter time frame if they don't need it.)

I am posting this for two reasons: 1) to help anyone trying to allow flexibility in date arguments and 2) to welcome sanity checks in case there's a problem with the method, since this is going into a function in an R package.

```
dat_time_check_fn <- function(dat_time) {
  if (!anyNA(as.Date(dat_time, format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))) date_type <- 1
else if (!anyNA(as.Date(dat_time, format= "%Y-%m-%d"))) date_type <- 2
else stop("Error: dates must either be in format '1999-12-31' or '1999-12-31 23:59:59' ")
date_type
}
```

Date-time case

```
date5 <- "1999-12-31 23:59:59"

date_type <- dat_time_check_fn(date5)
date_type
[1] 1
```

Date only case:

```
date6 <- "1999-12-31"

date_type <- dat_time_check_fn(date6)
date_type
[1] 2
```

Note that if the order above in the function is reversed, the longer date-time can be inadvertently coerced to the shorter version and both types result in date_type = 1.

My larger function has more than one date, but I need them to be compatible. Below, I'm checking the two dates checked above, where one was type 1 and one was type 2. Combining types gives the result with date only (type 2):

```
date_type <- dat_time_check_fn(c(date5, date6))
date_type
[1] 2
```

Here's a non-compliant version:

```
date7 <- "1/31/2011"

date_type <- dat_time_check_fn(date7)

Error in dat_time_check_fn(date7) : 
  Error: dates must either be in format '1999-12-31' or '1999-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 1):

Many solutions here are prone to SQL injection. They return `TRUE` for `date = "2020-08-11; DROP * FROM my_table"`. Here is a vectorized base R function that works with `NA`:

```r
is_date = function(x, format = NULL) {
  formatted = try(as.Date(x, format), silent = TRUE)
  is_date = as.character(formatted) == x & !is.na(formatted)  # valid and identical to input
  is_date[is.na(x)] = NA  # Insert NA for NA in x
  return(is_date)
}
```

Let's try:

```r
> is_date(c("2020-08-11", "2020-13-32", "2020-08-11; DROP * FROM table", NA), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
## TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are looking for is the **tryCatch** function. 
The following as an excerpt from a script I wrote which accepts any .csv file with two series that have a common x axis. The first column in 'data' is the common x axis variable, and columns 2 & 3 are the y axis variables. I needed the tryCatch statement to make sure the script would create a plot regardless of whether the x axis data is a time series, or some other type of variable.

```
### READ DATA FROM A CSV FILE
data = read.csv("STLDvsNEM2.csv", header = TRUE)

#CONVERT FIRST ROW OF DATA (IN MY CASE, THE COLUMN INTENDED TO BE THE X AXIS)
#TO AN ACCEPTABLE DATE FORMAT
#IF FIRST ROW OF DATA IS NOT IN AN ACCEPTABLE DATE FORMAT
#USE THE VALUE WITHOUT ANY TRANSFORMATION
x <- tryCatch({
  as.Date(data[,1])},
  warning = function(w) {},
  error = function(e) {
    x <- data[,1]
  })
y1 <- data[,2]
y2 <- data[,3]
```